# SYSDATE FROM DUAL in another SELECT

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I have problems with time in my select. Time in DB is different than system time so I guess I need to use `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL` but it doesn't work in another select. I use PL/SQL Developer.

```
SELECT t.something1,
       ROUND((TRUNC(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL) - 1 + 2),1) AS NAME
FROM customers t
WHERE t.something1 = ROUND((TRUNC(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL) - 1 + 2),1);
```

I have also tried to declare new variable but I always get error message.

```
DECLARE
day DATE
SELECT SYSDATE
INTO day
FROM DUAL
SELECT t.something1,
       ROUND((TRUNC(day)- 1 + 2),1) AS NAME
FROM customers t
WHERE t.something1 = ROUND((TRUNC(day) - 1 + 2),1);
```

Comment: why do you need DUAL?

Comment: When you use just SYSDATE it returns date of your system. But I need date of DB.

Comment: SYSDATE gives you date of your database server.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying here. Sysdate is a datetime. TRUNC makes it a date without a time part. But what is ROUND supposed to do? ROUND is for numbers, not for dates. And what exactly is your problem with SYSDATE? What do you want to select actually?

Comment: @astrak . . . What calculation are you trying to do?

Comment: are you connected to database that is in your local system or it's somewhere else??

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post original one. In this calculation I have two dates (one - another one and +- some numbers). When on DB is real (lets say human) time I get good result. But when there is different time I have wrong result...

Comment: Vote -1, nice :-) I wrote just sample code as required. In my case it works perfectly when DB time = real time. But when time is different it return wrong result. Anyone know where should be problem?

Answer (score 6):

You must use `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL` to get `SYSDATE` only if you have no table to select from. This is because a `SELECT` without a `FROM` is not valid with Oracle, so when you want to use a SQL function and you have no table, you have to use `DUAL`, which is a special one-row one-column (named `DUMMY`) table. The only row has the value `X`.

Answer (score 2):

[ROUND(number)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) function will only work with `number` data type. It will not work with the `date` type.
If your `t.something1` column data type is date than you can't used round() function (you can directly compare date with date), if it not and is number than you will use round() and you need to convert your sysdate into number and compare.

As per my understanding you do something like below :

```
SELECT t.something1,
   ROUND(to_number(to_char(sysdate+1,'DDMMYYYY')),1) AS NAME
   FROM customers t
   WHERE t.something1 = ROUND(to_number(to_char(sysdate+1,'DDMMYYYY')),1);
```

May this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Yagnesh for the answer. I have already found where is problem. I needed to find days from certain day on database where we do time shift. My select worked on DB without time shift. But on DB where we do time shift is parameter +xxx days from current time. That I didn't know. Thanks everyone for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT t.something1,
       ROUND((TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 + 2),1) AS NAME
FROM customers t
WHERE t.something1 = ROUND((TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 + 2),1);
```

Does this fix your problem?

Comment: It would be really nice solution but it doesn't work. It return wrong date.